# How I can fix the "The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it."

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem with the collider on my game. On console I get this error: MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.

My code is:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
   if (collision.tag.Equals("Money"))
    {
        if (gameObject != null)
            Score.moneyAmount += 1;
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
    }

}
```

I tried to make the gameObject null but it's not working. 
Can someone please help?

This is all the error if it's help:
`MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
UnityEngine.Object.Internal_InstantiateSingle (UnityEngine.Object data, UnityEngine.Vector3 pos, UnityEngine.Quaternion rot) <0x1505ad3c0 + 0x0006a> in <326982e5f7d84df7b8fe3152df5f407e>:0
UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate (UnityEngine.Object original, UnityEngine.Vector3 position, UnityEngine.Quaternion rotation) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEngineObject.bindings.cs:211)
UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate[T] (T original, UnityEngine.Vector3 position, UnityEngine.Quaternion rotation) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEngineObject.bindings.cs:285)
moneyfall.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/moneyfall.cs:24)`

and on moneyfall.cs line 24 is: 
`case 2: Instantiate(prefab2, transform.position, Quaternion.identity); break;`

Comment: `gameObject` is different than `collision.gameObject`; the `Destroy` is not guarded in the if statement; "tried to make the gameObject null" is not reflected in the code shown.

Comment: and how I can fix it?

Comment: Which line is causing the issue, why check if the item you are on is null, normally, if its null the scripts are terminated..

Comment: `case 2:
                    Instantiate(prefab2, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    break;` this is the line, as I can see in the console

Comment: But thats not in the code you pasted !!! ... Id guess prefab2 wasnt a prefab